# How to create geojson file from an existing json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, geojson

I have a json file which contains a location field which has geolocation ID of certain locations. What I want to do is to extract those geolocation fields and create a separate geojson file. Is there any way I can accomplish this task. This is the API url for JSON file >> https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects?format=json&countryshortname_exact=India&source=IBRD&kw=N&rows=1